# iPhone UITabBar based app + UITableView with details view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbar

I'm writing a UITabBar based iPhone application. One of the tab items is a UITableView and works perfectly. But now I'd like to add a detailed view, so I created one and tried to connect it with the TableView. But there's a problem, if I touch an item nothing happens, the selection appears but doesn't go to the details view and the selection doesn't disappear.
I wrote the codes based on an example that uses app delegate and so, these are the ones I cannot adapt to my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: some piece of code, where u wrote the selection of cell, is desired?

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement the function `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` of the `UITableViewDelegate`?

** EDIT **

As said in my comments, you need to implement a UINavigationController. here is an example on how to it using interface builder :

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/

Comment: Yes, I did. And I used the self.navigationController pushViewController.... The detailed view construct runs but doesn't appear..

Comment: Without code, hard to find, but my first guess would be to check if self.navigationController is different from 'nil'.

Comment: Yes, navigationController is nil ! What to do?

Comment: You need to implement a UINavigationController as the main view controller of your tab bar. And put the UIViewController that contains your UITableView as the root view controller of the UINavigationController. Are you using a XIB file or do everything by code?

Comment: How to implement UINavigationController as the main vc.? Should I change it in the app delegate file (overwrite this: self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;)? Will it affect the tabbar? It's a bit confusing me.. I'm using XIBs.

Comment: No, the rootViewController still need to be the tabBarController. I've updated my answer with a tutorial on how to implement the UINavigationController